# Ansible templating yaml inside a task

Tags: ansible, lxd

i am using the *lxd_container* module to create some lxd containers. One of these containers should include in its configuration the line **security.nesting: "true"**. I can't template this configuration since it is controlled by the lxc tool.
I need something like :

> {% if item.0 == "gitlab" %} security.nesting: true {% endif %}

```
- name: Creating  containers
  lxd_container:
    name: "{{item.0}}"
    state: started
    source:
      type: image
      mode: pull
      server: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases
      protocol: simplestreams
      alias: 18.04/amd64
    profiles: ["default"]
    config:
      security.nesting: true // only if item.0 == gitlab
      user.network-config: |-
        version: 1
        config:
          - type: physical
            name: eth0
            subnets:
              - type: static
                ipv4: true
                address: "{{ item.1 }}"
                netmask: 255.255.255.0
                gateway: "{{ CONT_GATEWAY }}"
                control: auto
    timeout: 7000
  with_together: 
  - "{{ CONT_NAME }}"
  - "{{ CONT_IP_ADRESS }}"
```

how could i achieve  this in one task ?

Answer (score 0):

Would [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) help you?

```
- set_fact:
    nesting: "{{ (item0 == 'gitlab') | ternary(true, omit) }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ nesting|default('NOT SET') }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you just do:

`security.nesting: "{{item.0 == gitlab}}"`